# Extracting number of links from a website

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I would need to extract the number of links in a website, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask (just for example)

I have tried to use `urlparse` to extract url information, then beautiful soup.

```
domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
```

I would need to save in a list all the links in the website for each website. I would like to have something like this:

```
URL                                            Links
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask    ['link1','link2','link3',...]
    https://anotherwebsite.com/sport           ['link1','link2','link3','link4']
    https://last_example.es                    []
```

Could you please explain me how to get similar results?

Comment: Your question is too general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
def get_all_links(url):
    # of course one needs to deal with the case when `requests` fails
    # but that's outside the scope here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    return [a.attrs.get('href', '') for a in soup.find_all('a')]

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'URL':['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask']})


df['Links'] = df['URL'].apply(get_all_links)
```

Output:

```
                                       URL                                              Links
0  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask  [#, https://stackoverflow.com, /company, #, /t...
```

Comment: food for thought: if you want to remove the duplicates change the return item to: list(set(a.attrs.get('href', '') for a in soup.find_all('a'))) or if you want to limit what's returned to have only a certain url or portion you can do: list(set(a.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('stackoverflow.com'))))